# JSF runtime pagename passing

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jsf-2

I have an include page which is a navigation menu. When i click on those menu i want to refresh the content area of layout with a certain page. How can i pass the page name into a JSF page using include tag

I dont want to switch to facelets and also i tried using $ and calling the backing bean method. It works but no css or richfaces components renders properly.

Thanks
Raj

Comment: Are you really using JSF 2.0 on JSP?

Comment: Yea. JSF 2.0 and Rich faces 3.x . I just want to pass the page name to jsp include tag @ run time

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the RichFaces part, but you can just use EL in `<jsp:include>` as well.

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/#{bean.pagename}.jsp" />
```

If `bean.getPagename()` returns for example `home`, then this will include `/WEB-INF/home.jsp`. You also need to ensure that the JSF/HTML contents of `home.jsp` is wrapped by a `<f:subview>` with an unique ID.

As to the CSS trouble, just ensure that the generated HTML [validates](http://validator.w3.org/) and that the CSS imports in the `<link>` tags are all valid.

Comment: I tried this         <jsp:include page="#{panelMenu.current}" />
and this is what i get in browser-- The requested resource (/cdclassifieds/members/#{panelMenu.current}) is not available 
Please help

Comment: Did you declare `web.xml` to be Servlet 2.5? This sounds like as if it's Servlet 2.4. Unified EL in template text would then indeed not be parsed. I'd update the `web.xml` to comply Servlet 2.5 (if your appserver supports it). You can also use `${panelMenu.current}`, but if it's a request scoped bean which is to be created yet, then you need to ensure as well that you've called `#{panelMenu.xxx}` somewhere before the `jsp:include` line with `${}`. JSF will then create the bean if not created. The `${}` namely won't do that.

Comment: Also see this article http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/01/dynamic-jsf-subviews.html

Comment: Hey Balu .. Thanks for your help .. I tried the things mentioned in the article and this is what i get in error stack 

java.lang.NullPointerException
 javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.doPostAddProcessing(UIComponentBase.java:1691)
 javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setParent(UIComponentBase.java:403)